# How to rewrite this php filterArray function for better performance

Tags: php, arrays, function, filtering

I have a filterArray method in a class which I use for filtering out an array based on another:

```
function filterArray($needle, $heystack, $always = array())
{
    foreach($heystack as $k => $v)
    {
        if( !in_array($v, $needle) && !in_array($v, $always) )
            unset($heystack[$k]);
    }

    return $heystack;
}
```

Usage:

```
$chars  = array('l', 'J', 'F');
$keys   = array('d','D','j','l','N','S','w','z','W','F','m','M','n','t','L','o','Y','y','a','A','c','r','e','T');
$keys   = filterArray($chars, $keys, array('z'));
```

note that `$always` is an array of items that should always be present and should not be filtered out. The result of key is:

```
$keys   = array('l', 'J', 'F', 'z');
```

This is more of a validation process. Is there a better way to write this and optimize it for performace? because it's used in a class where performance is crucial.

Thank you.

Comment: `in_array`  is slow, use a linked-list

Comment: @DevZer0 That's PHP >= 5.3 my code requires 5.2+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didn't specify if there is a need to maintain key association, if key association is not required you can do the following function.

```
function filterArray($needle, $heystack, $always = array())
{
    return array_intersect(array_merge($needle, $always), $heystack);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the one. It's much faster. Executed in 0.000007 Seconds on my machine while the old version was executed in 0.0001 second

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
function filterArray($needle, $heystack, $always = array()) {

    $merged = array_merge($needle, $always);

    return array_intersect($heystack, $merged);
}
```